# OffsetDateTime now gives different time on server side

Tags: java, time

When I use the `OffsetDateTime.now()` in my unit tests I receive the same time as I see on my clock hanging on the wall.
But when it comes to deploy app and debug I see this time -2h hours.
How do I deal with this?

Also, how to treat this execution time, if a user can do the same thing and they come from many different places?

How can I execute something `now()` if I come from other localization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this [`now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) method to get rid of dependency on time zone of server. Pass either a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) object or a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) object.

```
public static OffsetDateTime now(ZoneId zone)
```

Comment: Fine, but dont be mad, but if I want to always have now(). on PCs which are located in different places in the world I would have to always check the timezone of client?

Thanks!

Comment: @Ernesto you can use it `now()` method, but keep in mind that your unit tests should not have any dependency on external things like timezone, os, etc.